# form submission in another domain using jquery from chrome extension

Tags: jquery, forms, web-scraping, form-submit, onsubmit

I have scraped from data from one website using jquery. With the help of GET method. Now I want to submit that form But the problem is that the baseURI of form has been changed. So I'm not able to submit that form and as far as i know the baseURI is readonly so i can't change that.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done. All you can do is get the action URL or get the post API from network tab and scrape all the form data and then make a request with appropriate data.